What is an error barrier, and what does it do?
I'm looking at the libcu++ atomics to create some data structures.
When I write put the following code in compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/TqTePThG6
#include <cuda/atomic>
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void kernel(cuda::atomic<int, cuda::thread_scope_device>* a) {
  a->store(42, cuda::memory_order_release);
  const auto b = a->load(cuda::memory_order_acquire);
  a->store(b+2, cuda::memory_order_release);
  printf("b: %i\n", b);
}

int main() {}

Generates the following ptx byte code:
mov.u64         %SPL, __local_depot0;
cvta.local.u64  %SP, %SPL;
ld.param.u64    %rd1, [kernel(cuda::__4::atomic<int, (cuda::std::__4::__detail::thread_scope)1>*)_param_0];
add.u64         %rd4, %SP, 0;
add.u64         %rd5, %SPL, 0;
mov.u32         %r1, 42;
st.release.gpu.b32 [%rd1], %r1;
ld.acquire.gpu.b32 %r2,[%rd1];
add.s32         %r3, %r2, 2;
st.release.gpu.b32 [%rd1], %r3;
...
//printf stuff

Which looks pretty much identical to the source code, the SASS (for sm_75, because compiler explorer runs on the T4) however looks different:
 IMAD.MOV.U32 R1, RZ, RZ, c[0x0][0x28] 
 IADD3 R1, R1, -0x8, RZ 
 IMAD.MOV.U32 R3, RZ, RZ, 0x2a 
 ULDC.64 UR4, c[0x0][0x160] 
 MEMBAR.ALL.GPU 
 ERRBAR                           <<-- ??
 ST.E.STRONG.GPU [UR4], R3 
 LD.E.STRONG.GPU R0, [UR4] 
 CCTL.IVALL 
 IADD3 R2, R0, 0x2, RZ 
 MEMBAR.ALL.GPU 
 ERRBAR                           <<-- ??
 ST.E.STRONG.GPU [UR4], R2 
 

I'm a bit disappointed to see memory barrier here, although it makes sense I guess if I want the stores to be globally visible, but what are the ERRBAR. The "documentation" just says 'error barrier', but that does not tell me much.
What is an error barrier and what does it do?

ARMv8 has a similar concept: ESB (error synchronization barrier). This instruction is part of the RAS extension and its purpose is to make sure all error interrupts (in general: events) are handled before the next instruction. The intended purpose is to "contain" errors. For example, if an user mode application access a corrupted memory line and load a poisoned value in r0, the implicit esb at each svc instruction prevent the kernel from operating on this invalid value (thereby "containing" the error by executing SErr first). I don't know how this relates to Nvidia GPUs though :)
